# Reverse sort order of a multicolumn file in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sorting, awk

I've the following file:

```
1 2 3
1 4 5
1 6 7
2 3 5
5 2 1
```

and I want that the file be sorted for the second column but from the largest number (in this case 6) to the smallest. I've tried with

```
sort +1 -2 file.dat
```

but it sorts in ascending order (rather than descending).

The results should be:

```
1 6 7
1 4 5
2 3 5
5 2 1
1 2 3
```

Comment: `sort` has `-r` as an option, where "r" stands for "reverse". Have you tried that?

Comment: see here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/sort-contents-of-file-based-upon-fields.html   or  http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/sort-based-on-column-and-characters.html

Comment: For you `-r` answerers, it did not work for me.  `-nrk` did however

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
sort -nrk 2,2
```

does the trick.

n for numeric sorting, r for reverse order and k 2,2 for the second column.

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried -r ? From [the man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort):

> -r, --reverse
>
> ```
>           reverse the result of comparisons
> ```

Answer (score 3):

As mention most version of `sort` have the `-r` option if yours doesn't try `tac`:

```
$ sort -nk 2,2 file.dat | tac 
1 6 7
1 4 5
2 3 5
5 2 1
1 2 3

$ sort -nrk 2,2 file.dat 
1 6 7
1 4 5
2 3 5
5 2 1
1 2 3
```

> tac - concatenate and print files in reverse