# Linux sort by column and in reverse order

Tags: shell, sorting

I'm trying to sort a file by second column, but in reverse order.
I tried:

```
sort -k2n -r file.txt
```

The output is not in reverse order, so it seems -r is being ignored.
I'm in CentOS.

Comment: This is neither a programming question nor does the "linux" tag fit (see its description!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to remove the "n" next to column number:

```
sort -k 2 -r file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a space after the -k and before the column position. e.g. something like below

```
sort -k 2n -r file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks I tried but didn't work :(

Comment: can you post some sample data ? Also try with this ```sort -nrk 2,2 file.txt``` base on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120846/reverse-sort-order-of-a-multicolumn-file-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

Say we have `this.txt`

```
one 1
two 2
three 3
four 4
five 5
```

Now simply do

```
$ sort -k2,2nr this.txt 
five 5
four 4
three 3
two 2
one 1
```